# Residency for Out of State Student Getting Married

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ohio, michigan

I am a graduate student in Michigan but still consider my permanent residence to be in Ohio, as I plan to return there after graduation. I am able to just file income taxes with Ohio, as the two states have a reciprocity agreement.

My fiance just moved up to live with me in Michigan and she withholds state taxes for Michigan at her new job. We are getting married later this year.

If we want to file our taxes jointly once we are married should we both establish Michigan residency even though we plan on leaving after I graduate?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Is your fiancé also a student?  It sounds like the answer is no.  I think once you become married, you will jointly become residents because your wife is not in school.  However, I strongly suggest you contact the Michigan Department of Treasury directly and ask them.